# Excel conditions across multiple tables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm having a fairly complicated excel sheet. But i need probably a simple solution..
I have 2 sheets in my workbook one containing companies with contactdetails and one with events (hosted by those companies)

```
// Company Sheet
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ Company   ║ Contact      ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ Dominoes  ║ John Doe     ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
// Event sheet
╔═══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦═════════════╗
║ Events    ║ Company  ║ Payed ║    Date     ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║Pizza Party║ Dominoes ║  Yes  ║  06-07-2016 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║Pizza Swim ║ Dominoes ║  No   ║  07-07-2016 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║FREE PIZZA ║ Dominoes ║  No   ║  08-07-2016 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩═════════════╝
```

Now with conditional formatting i'd like to color the company sheet and mark the company as a `payer` or `not payer`.

The query has to do the following:

- Loop through every event by the company
- Check if the company payed the bill
- If date is not due the company doesnt have to pay

So for this example `Pizza Party` is paid and due date so this would return `FALSE`.

The `Pizza Swim` event is not payed and **is** due. This would return a `TRUE`

The `FREE PIZZA` event is not paid and the date is not due yet. This would return in a `FALSE` too

If the company does not pay it bills (`TRUE`) the company will be marked **red**
If the company did pay his bills (`FALSE`) the company will be marked **green**

If there are multiple events by one company the outcome `TRUE` will overrule every other paid bill (`FALSE`)

How to accomplish this?

I've tried it with a function:

`=IF(Table2[Company]=A2;IF(Table2[Payed]="Ja";FALSE;IF(Table2[Date]<Today();TRUE;FALSE));TRUE)`

Comment: Great requirements - what code did you try and write?

Comment: How is this question too broad?
I've explicitly said the conditions.

Comment: There are several ways to achieve the outcome including formulas and VBA - so many choices. If you post the code you tried then that would help. PS I didn't vote.

Comment: @Robin I've tried it with a query as i supposed it wouldn't be that hard so it'd need vba but i'm not afraid to add vba ;). And i figured out that you didn't vote

Comment: Which cell do you want to be colored based on the provided data?

Comment: @RGA The complete row of the company within the company table

Comment: Have you tried to make a pivot table over the Events as a helper?
In the rows, group by Company, and in the columns, group by Payed. And as value , count the number of true and false. This way, you get a nice matrix which you can use for formatting your company sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more clever way to do this using conditional formatting and functions, but I'm more of a VBA guy so I wrote a quick sub that should do what you want with some mild adjustments

```
Sub MarkNonPayers()
    Dim CompanySheet As Worksheet, EventSheet As Worksheet, Cell As Range, UnpayingCompany As String, FoundCell As Range
    Set CompanySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Company Sheet")
    Set EventSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Event Sheet")
    UnpayingCompany = "><"
    For Each Cell In EventSheet.Range(EventSheet.Cells(2,1),EventSheet.Cells(EventSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,1))

         If EventSheet.Cells(Cell.Row,"M").Value = "No" And CDate(EventSheet.Cells(Cell.Row,"E").Value) - Date(Now) < 0 Then
             Set FoundCell = CompanySheet.UsedRange.Find(EventSheet.Cells(Cell.Row,"A").Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
           CompanySheet.Range(CompanySheet.Cells(FoundCell.Row, "A"), CompanySheet.Cells(FoundCell.Row,"K").Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
         UnpayingCompany = UnpayingCompany & EventSheet.Cells(Cell.Row,"A").Value & "><"
         End If

    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In CompanySheet.Range(CompanySheet.Cells(2,1),CompanySheet.Cells(CompanySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,1))
        If Len(UnpayingCompany) - Len(Replace(UnpayingCompany,"<" & Cell.Value & ">", "")) = 0 AND Not IsEmpty(Cell.Value) AND Cell.Value <> "Total" Then
            CompanySheet.Range(CompanySheet.Cells(Cell.Row,"A"), CompanySheet.Cells(Cell.Row, "K")).Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: My sheets are a little different than posted here
The Event Sheet payed column is: Column M
The event sheet Date column is: Column E
The event sheet Company column is: Column A
The event sheet eventname is: Column B
The company sheet Company column is: A
The company sheet Contact column is: D

Comment: @Baklap4 See the editted code.  this should properly find the specified values

Comment: when running this script i'm getting a "Type Mismatched" Error 13.
Am I doing something strange here?
The data resides in a Table with Headers (Maybe that's need to know)?

Comment: @Baklap4 thats exactly it.  It was trying to pass a string header to a Date type and failing.  I've adjusted the code again to reflect that fix (just start the search range in row 2 instead of 1

Comment: @Baklap4 it is possible that you may get this error again if excel has trouble interpretting a date value from the dates you have inputted.  Is that column formatted for dates or are they simple string values?  If they are strings and it is having issues, we can adjust the code to change the string text so that CDate() will work properly

Comment: Alright! It does not crash anymore while running! How would one run this script when column `M` in the event sheet changes (from `No` to `Yes`) As for now i have to rerun the script all the time by hand which is not very nice

Comment: @Baklap4 Open the worksheet_Change event (a quick google should show you how to write that), and have this code run whenever `Target.Cells.Count = 1 AND Target.Column = "M"`

Comment: @Baklap4 you will need to run it *once* after you have implemented it to change all the values in the sheets, but from there it will run anytime the value changes

Comment: @Baklap4  See the editted code.  I realized that the code as written would not "unmark" companies that had once been marked Red but had now payed.  Now, the code will properly mark paying companies as Green and unpaying as Red, properly updating them as values change

Comment: If i'm right the Replace call in the last if expects another parameter namely the `replacement` parameter as this one is not optional

Comment: Hmm Right now i have it added to the change event. But it will draw everything green now hmm

Comment: @Baklap4 I made a silly mistake with my string list.  Code is adjusted and should (fingers crossed) work as intended now

Comment: Nopes still all greenish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116685/discussion-between-baklap4-and-rga).

Answer (score 0):

Do you not just need something like the following as your conditional formatting rule:

```
=AND(C2="No",D2<=TODAY())
```

Comment: This won't do the trick 
if it all was contained in one big table it would do the trick but as there's just one table with companies i need to have a connection between those companies and the events list
Then depending on my conditions we'll loop through the eventresultset of one company to see if they meet my conditions

Comment: So if any of the events are not payed then you want to highlight the company?

Comment: If all are paid except for one (for example) the company will be highlighted Red
If all are paid (in time) the company will be listed green :)

Comment: OK, so change what I gave you before so it's a helper column (E): =IF(AND(C2="No",D2<=TODAY()),1,0) and then in your other sheet use SUMIFS to test if that needs paying: =SUMIFS(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$7,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,Sheet2!A2)>0